# Apache Camel Spring remote not working

Tags: apache-camel, spring-remoting

Given a server configuration:

```
<camel:camelContext id="reporting_shoppingCard"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:contextScan />

    <camel:export uri="activemq:queue:bshop.reports.shoppingCard"
        serviceRef="reportingService"
        serviceInterface="bshop.reporting.shoppingcard.ReportingService" />

</camel:camelContext>
```

... a client configuration:

```
<camelContext id="reporting_shoppingCard" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:contextScan />

    <camel:proxy id="reportingServiceProxy"
        serviceInterface="bshop.reporting.ReportingService"
        serviceUrl="activemq:queue:bshop.reports.shoppingCard" />

</camelContext>
```

... an interface with one method:

```
package bshop.reporting;

public interface ReportingService {
    public byte[] createShoppingCardReport(Long aShoppingCardId);
}
```

.. and an implementation of the service:

```
package bshop.reporting.shoppingcard;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import bshop.reporting.ReportingService;

@Service("reportingService")
public class ReportingServiceImpl implements ReportingService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportingServiceImpl.class);

/**
 * @see bshop.reporting.ReportingService#createShoppingCardReport(java.lang.Long)
 */
@Override
public byte[] createShoppingCardReport(Long aShoppingCardId) {
    logger.info("Creating shoppingCard report for shoppingCard ID {}", aShoppingCardId);
    return new byte[20];
}
}
```

When calling the proxy ..

```
getReportingServiceProxy().createShoppingCardReport(shoppingCardId);
```

the BeanIvocation will be routed to the **ActiveMQ.DLQ** queue instead of **bshop.reports.shoppingCard**, and the Service impl. won't be called.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Camel: 2.11.1
ActiveMQ: 5.5.1-fuse-03-06

My CLIENT jms broker config:

```
<!-- ######### JMS Broker configuration -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${brokerURL}"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>
<!-- ######### -->
```

My SERVER jms broker config:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${brokerURL}" />
</bean>
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>
```

The ActiveMQ log shows:

```
2014-08-22 16:07:27,067 | DEBUG | localhost adding destination: queue://bshop.reports.shoppingCard | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,071 | DEBUG | bshop.reports.shoppingCard toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,071 | DEBUG | queue://bshop.reports.shoppingCard add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:edc-derasu220-37838-1408540697354-0:158:1:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,073 | DEBUG | localhost adding destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.bshop.reports.shoppingCard | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,122 | DEBUG | Message expired ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:M3-55082-1408711759949-0:141:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:M3-55082-1408711759949-0:141:1:1, destination = queue://bshop.reports.shoppingCard, transactionId = null, expiration = 1408716051506, timestamp = 1408716031506, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1408716447076, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = Camel-ID-M3-54934-1408711481855-0-7, replyTo = temp-queue://ID:M3-55082-1408711759949-0:139:1, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@a30589, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false} | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,122 | DEBUG | localhost adding destination: queue://ActiveMQ.DLQ | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,125 | DEBUG | ActiveMQ.DLQ toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,128 | DEBUG | localhost Message ID:M3-55082-1408711759949-0:141:1:1:1 sent to queue://ActiveMQ.DLQ | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,128 | DEBUG | ActiveMQ.DLQ toPageIn: 1, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:ActiveMQ.DLQ
2014-08-22 16:07:27,141 | DEBUG | localhost adding destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDLQd.Queue.bshop.reports.shoppingCard | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,142 | DEBUG | localhost adding destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue.bshop.reports.shoppingCard | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
2014-08-22 16:07:27,145 | DEBUG | localhost removing consumer: ID:M3-55082-1408711759949-0:141:-1:1 for destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.23.26.29:58206
```

Comment: I see your interface called ReportingServiceSync. ReportingServiceImpl implements **ReportingService**. Where does ReportingService come from? Just curious

Comment: I'm sorry, the interface name is ReportingService, not ReportingServiceSync. I will correct my post.

Comment: Can we see your ActiveMQ component configuration as well as the list of queues that you have created (to ensure queue name matches, etc.)

Comment: Configuration added. I don't have a list of queues, since the camel configuration manage the existency of queues. So my queues are configured in the camel configs.

Comment: ok, so I notice that **<bean id="jms" ...>** is your component defined. **activemq** is the component you are using in both server and client. Does your server and client use the same config file?

Comment: I changed the routes to use the **jms**, same behavior :(

Comment: Again, does your client and server use the same component config file or do they each have their own? Also, if you have any trace logs for both the client and server showing route startup and endpoint configuration detail that would be helpful.

Comment: The configurations are the same (both added). In the logs I do not see any hints to the problem. Everything looks fine. I noticed, that the behavior doesn't depend on a running server. The server may be down, the message will be routed to *ActiveMQ.DLQ* too.

Comment: So, this is because the messages expire after a set amount of time. If the message isn't consumed from the queue before the expiration timestamp, then it is moved to the DLQ. You can see the header value: **expiration = 1408716051506**. Your server absolutely needs to be running for this to work--since it is not working, the problem is with your server's consumer endpoint. Do you have start up logs of the server?

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that your server has an incorrect serviceInterface package path: serviceInterface="bshop.reporting.**shoppingcard**.ReportingService". The shoppingcard portion shouldn't be there according to the ReportinService class. I'll add this as the answer along with my previous comment if this works for you

Comment: If the server is running, the message will be routed to the ActiveMQ.DLQ immediately too. There is no difference in the behavior, if the server is running or not.

Comment: That is because your server is not **consuming** the message (obviously). The client produces fine, but the message expires because nothing consumes it. Did you fix your package path for your serviceInterface--I believe this is contributing to your server's issues.

Comment: The package paths are fine (i changed them only for this post, to hide some company names). The server is running and awaiting messages on the queue: **bshop.reports.shoppingCard**. If I change the client to use a template for sending the message, and use **ExchangePattern.InOut**, the message goes to AcitveMQ.DLQ. But, if I send the message with ExchangePattern.InOnly, the message arrive at the right destination. So, I think it has something to do with the configuration of the route. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The reason was the **expiration** of the message. Unfortunately my client ran on my notebook, which had a different time set as the server. The message sent from my client was already expired on the server, so camel routed the message straight forward to the **ActiveMQ.DLQ**.

Thank you, Dakota, for your help!